# What caused Curiosity's electrical trouble?

Tags: mars, curiosity

According to [this NASA announcement](http://www.nasa.gov/jpl/msl/mars-rover-curiosity-20131125.html#.UpaeY2RDs1A), there seems to have been some kind of trouble with Curiosity's electrical system:

> The decision to resume science activities resulted from the success of work to diagnose the likely root cause of a Nov. 17 change in voltage on the vehicle. The voltage change itself did not affect the rover safety or health. The vehicle's electrical system has a "floating bus" design feature to tolerate a range of voltage differences between the vehicle's chassis -- its mechanical frame -- and the 32-volt power lines that deliver electricity throughout the rover. This protects the rover from electrical shorts.

However, I wasn't able to find anything on what actually caused the jolt. What is thought to have caused it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[image]
                                                       <sup>Curiosity before launch (img credit [The Atlantic](http://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2012/08/curiosity-lands-on-mars-know-what-youre-watching-when-youre-watching-7-minutes-of-terror/260725/))</sup>

According to [this space.com article](http://www.space.com/23735-mars-rover-curiosity-glitch-recovery.html) (and several other sources), the most likely cause was an internal short in Curiosity's radioisotope thermoelectric generator (RTG) - the thingy that converts the heat of radioactive decay into electricity to power the rover.

[image]
                                                       <sup>Curiosity's RTG (img credit [Extreme Tech](http://www.extremetech.com/extreme/150756-to-the-stars-after-a-25-year-hiatus-nasa-restarts-plutonium-production))</sup>

Luckily, it appears that the rover won't be negatively affected in the long run - from the same article:

> "Due to resiliency in design, this short does not affect operation of the power source or the rover," NASA officials wrote in a Curiosity status update today (Nov. 25). "Similar generators on other spacecraft, including NASA's Cassini at Saturn, have experienced shorts with no loss of capability."

According to many sources (like [this one](http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/politics-and-nation/mars-rover-curiosity-bounces-back-from-electrical-glitch/articleshow/26474534.cms)), the rover has a 'floating bus' between the 32-volt main power lines in the vehicle and the metal frame - thus protecting it from huge shorts.

According to [this wonderful answer to my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/92086/29392), a floating bus

> doesn't share grounds between the two systems it is connecting. It does so by using either optical or magnetic links instead of voltage levels to transfer data.

[image]

This allows two systems to be connected, but not be compromised if one fails - it's much like a wall made of bulletproof glass: You can't shoot whatever's on the other side, but you can still pound on the wall or perform another 'safe' action to get a message to the other side.

> **tl;dr**: the rover is going to be okay - there was an internal short in the RTG, but history has shown that this kind of issue doesn't tend to break things too badly.